# GeomFromText in trigger has error

Tags: mysql, trigger, spatial, percona, mysql-5.6

I have this trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER geometrytrigger BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.user_geometry=GeomFromText(NEW.user_geometry);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

when I insert a row with this query:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `user_geometry`) VALUES (NULL, 'arash', 'arash@host.com', 'sssssss', 'POINT(-0.23 169.93)');
```

this error has occurred:

```
 #1416 - Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

**edit**:

```
show create table users;
```

result:

```
Table   Create Table    
users   CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin DEFAULT NULL,
 `password` binary(40) NOT NULL,
 `user_geometry` geometry DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Also I use Percona 5.6.12 or MySQL 5.6.12

Answer (score 2):

The error isn't coming from the trigger.   You could confirm this by dropping the trigger and you will see the same error.

```
ERROR 1416 (22003): Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field
```

You didn't mention it in the question, but it looks like your `user_geometry` column is defined with a `GEOMETRY` data type.  To use a `GEOMETRY` data type, you have to insert a `GEOMETRY` object.  You can't coerce it later with a trigger because it's validated very early, before the `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger.

Remove the quotes and add a comma and you have a query that would work and not need the trigger:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `user_geometry`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'arash', 'arash@host.com', 'sssssss', POINT(-0.23,169.93));
```

The [POINT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/creating-spatial-values.html#function_point) function takes 2 arguments and returns a geometry object.

Comment: I can remove quotes, because the insert statement produced by ORM , and ORM put quotes around strings, this ORM hasn't support for MySQL expressions,SO I can only send string value in query. because of this situation write this trigger. any other approach?

Comment: Ah. Yes, there are some possible workarounds. Please edit your question to add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for the table, so that I can see column types, nullability, and indexes, and I'll suggest a solution. Also please provide your exact MySQL version.

Comment: I edited my question.